# friend function is not assigning values to class's array

Tags: c++, function, class, friend

i'm new to C++ programming and i created this program for vector matrix multiplication,everything is working fine , except results are not stored in my class's array(i'm using friend function to do multiplication and assign result) . here is my code:

**a simpler code is at the end of page**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrice.hpp"
#include "vecteur.hpp"
#include "vecteurv.hpp"
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double M[3][3];
    double *p;
    p=(double*)M;
    double vect[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("M[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%lf",(p+i*3+j)); 
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("V[%d]=",i);
        scanf("%lf",&vect[i]);
    }

    vecteur v(vect);//entered array vect
    matrice m(*M);//entered matrix 
    m.afficher(m);//printing matrix
    v.afficher(v);//printing array vect
    produit(v,m);//calculating matrix*vect
    v.afficherVL(v);//printing the result (it is not showing values)


    

    
    return 0;
}
```

matrice.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vecteur.hpp"
#ifndef MATRICE_HPP
#define MATRICE_HPP
class vecteur;
class matrice {
    public:
    double M[3][3];
    public:
    matrice();
    matrice(double *);
    double getm(int i,int j);
    void afficher(matrice M);
    friend void produit(vecteur ,matrice );
};

#endif
```

matrice.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrice.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cmax 3
matrice::matrice()
{
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            M[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
matrice::matrice(double *Mat)
{
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            double *p;
            double *p2;
            p=(double*)M;
            p2=(double*)Mat;
            *(p+i*cmax+j)=*(p2+i*cmax+j);
        }
    }
}

void matrice::afficher(matrice M)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\nLa matrice:\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf\t",M.M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



double matrice::getm(int i,int j)
{
            return M[i][j];
}
```

vecteur.hpp

```
#ifndef VECTEUR_HPP
#define VECTEUR_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include "matrice.hpp"

class vecteur {
    double V[3];
    double VL[3];
    public:
    double getv(int i);
    void set_result(double *val,int i);
    void set(double*);
    vecteur();
    vecteur(double*);
    void afficher(vecteur L);
    void afficherVL(vecteur);
    friend void produit(vecteur ,matrice );
};



#endif
```

vecteur.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vecteur.hpp"
#include "matrice.hpp"
using namespace std;
vecteur::vecteur()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        V[i]=0;
    }
}

vecteur::vecteur(double* vect)
{
    double *p;
    p=&vect[0];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        V[i]=*(p+i);
    }
}

void vecteur::afficher(vecteur L)
{
    printf("\nvector before calculating:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\t",L.V[i]);
    }
}

void vecteur::afficherVL(vecteur L)
{
    printf("\nvector after calculating:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\t",L.VL[i]);
    }
}


void vecteur::set_result(double *val,int i)
{
    double *p;
    p=&VL[0];
    *(p+i)=*val;
}
double vecteur::getv(int i)
{
    return V[i];
}
```

vecteurv.hpp it contains class with function produit only

```
#ifndef VECTEURV_HPP
#define VECTEURV_HPP
#include <iostream>
class vecteur;
class matrice;
class vecteurv{
    public:
    friend void produit(vecteur,matrice);
    
};

#endif
```

produit.cpp

```
#include "vecteur.hpp"
#include "matrice.hpp"
class vecteur;
class matrice;
void produit(vecteur R,matrice M1)
{
double Result;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            Result=R.getv(i)+(M1.getm(i,j)*(R.getv(j)));
            
        }
        R.set_result(&Result,i);//entering values to the vector (array) VL in class inside "vecteur.hpp"
        printf("\nentered %lf",Result);//to test if Result is getting values
        
    }


}
```

is there anything wrong with the way i used the friend function?

here is my execution:

[only results are not assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7RAw.png)

**simple code**

friend class with produit prototype

```
#ifndef VECTEURV_HPP
#define VECTEURV_HPP
#include <iostream>
class vecteur;
class matrice;
class vecteurv{
    public:
    friend void produit(vecteur,matrice);
    
};

#endif
```

produit function (friend function)

```
#include "vecteur.hpp"
#include "matrice.hpp"
class vecteur;
class matrice;
void produit(vecteur R,matrice M1)
{
double Result;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            Result=R.V[i]+(M1.M[i][j]*(R.V[j]));
            
        }
        R.(VL+i)=Result;//entering values to the vector (array) VL in class inside "vecteur.hpp"
        printf("\nentered %lf",Result);//to test if Result is getting values
        
    }


}
```

V[i]  //V is member of vecteur class where i assigned array values
M[i][j] //M is member of matrice class where i assigned matrix values

VL[i] //VL is member of vecteur class where function produit assigns result to it

the problem is that function produit is not assigning values to VL array.

i may have a mistake in writing in **main.cpp** the code for main.cpp is at the top

Comment: You need to pass by reference: `void produit(vecteur R,matrice M1)` -> `void produit(vecteur& R, matrice& M1)`, otherwise you are calling `set_result` on a local copy (and you also need to modify your friend declarations too)

Comment: @Artyer thank you , it is working now